# Skipping code blocks in antlr4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

For example,program : I have a grammar file as follows:

```
grammar fileName;

program : 'start' statements+ 'end';

statements : print;

print: 'output' STRING;

STRING : ["] ( ~["\r\n\\] | '\\' ~[\r\n] )* ["] | ['] ( ~['\r\n\\] | '\\' ~[\r\n] )* ['];
```

Now I have a code as follows:

```
begin
  output "Hello World"
end

begin
  output "Hello World 2"
end
```

Now after that I want to check if the string of the output is Hello World 2, skip it and don't parse the 'statement' block and move on.

Is it possible to make antlr4 skip parsing a code block in the listener class?

PS: I am asking this question so I can implement it with my if, while, for and foreach statements. Such as skipping a code block when an if statement returns false, I just use this code as an example. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't parse the block, how can you know where it ends? The way to do it is parse everything (i.e. even non-executed code must be valid) and only skip the evaluation in listener.

Comment: @JiriTousek Yes, but how exactly do you do that?

Comment: That depends on how you implement the listener or visitor. The key part is though that it is not something you should solve in parser.

Comment: Again a misunderstanding of proper separation of the various steps in such projects. You *don't* want to evaluate the input while you parse!. Parsing is just the syntactic step. After that you do the semantic step, walk with your listener over the generated parse tree and use what you need and ignore the other branches. I hope it is obvious for you that skipping a tree branch only means not to do anything with it while the listener/visitor walks through it.

Comment: @MikeLischke thanks for the explaination, I will try to implement it in my program.